# Creating a UIElementQuery based off of a UIHierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

I have a layered UI that I'm trying to create a UI test for. I'm working without a deep understanding of how the UI is constructed, but I do have full access to the source code.

I'm trying to tap a button that pops up to "Confirm" deletion of a particular entry. However, I'm not able to craft a query in Swift that would give me the correct button to tap. Here's the full dump from the error:

```
UI Test Activity: 
Assertion Failure: ProfileScreen.swift:77: Failed to get matching snapshot: Multiple matching elements found for <XCUIElementQuery: 0x6000007c4d20>.
Sparse tree of matches:
→Application, pid: 92707, label: '******'
  ↳Window (Main)
  ⋅ ↳Other
  ⋅   ↳Other
  ⋅     ↳Button, identifier: 'Remove', label: 'Remove'
  ↳Window
    ↳Other
      ↳Other
        ↳Other
          ↳Other
            ↳Other
              ↳Other
                ↳Other
                  ↳Other
                    ↳Other
                      ↳Other
                        ↳Other
                          ↳Other
                            ↳CollectionView
                              ↳Cell, Selected
                              ⋅ ↳Other
                              ⋅   ↳Button, label: 'Remove'
                              ↳Cell
                                ↳Other
                                  ↳Button, label: 'Remove'
Possibly caused by runtime issues:
Automation type mismatch: computed Other from legacy attributes vs StaticText from modern attribute. Input attributes and values: {
    "XC_kAXXCAttributeAutomationType" = 48;
    "XC_kAXXCAttributeElementBaseType" = UILabel;
    "XC_kAXXCAttributeElementType" = UILabel;
    "XC_kAXXCAttributeTraits" = 8590000128;
}
See test report attachments for more detail.
```

The query that I have to generate that error is this:

`XCUIApplication().buttons["Remove"].tap()`

And the actual UIHierarchy:

```
  Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
    Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
        Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
          Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
            Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
              Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                  Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                    NavigationBar, {{0.0, 44.0}, {414.0, 44.0}}, identifier: 'Payment Information'
                      Button, {{0.0, 44.0}, {44.0, 44.0}}, label: 'Settings'
                      StaticText, {{139.5, 58.5}, {135.0, 17.0}}, label: 'Payment Information'
                    Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
                        Other, {{0.0, 88.0}, {414.0, 808.0}}
                          Other, {{0.0, 88.0}, {414.0, 808.0}}
                            CollectionView, {{0.0, 88.0}, {414.0, 808.0}}
                              Cell, {{0.0, 88.0}, {414.0, 72.0}}, Selected
                                Other, {{0.0, 88.0}, {414.0, 72.0}}
                                  Image, {{24.0, 115.0}, {18.0, 18.0}}
                                  Image, {{58.0, 110.0}, {49.5, 28.0}}
                                  StaticText, {{123.5, 114.5}, {36.0, 19.5}}, label: '1111'
                                  Button, {{331.0, 108.5}, {59.0, 31.0}}, label: 'Remove'
                                    StaticText, {{331.0, 114.5}, {59.0, 19.0}}, label: 'Remove'
                                  Other, {{0.0, 159.5}, {414.0, 0.5}}
                              Cell, {{0.0, 160.0}, {414.0, 72.0}}
                                Other, {{0.0, 160.0}, {414.0, 72.0}}
                                  Image, {{24.0, 187.0}, {18.0, 18.0}}
                                  Image, {{58.0, 182.0}, {49.5, 28.0}}
                                  StaticText, {{123.5, 186.5}, {36.0, 19.5}}, label: '2222'
                                  Button, {{331.0, 180.5}, {59.0, 31.0}}, label: 'Remove'
                                    StaticText, {{331.0, 186.5}, {59.0, 19.0}}, label: 'Remove'
                                  Other, {{0.0, 231.5}, {414.0, 0.5}}
                              Cell, {{0.0, 232.0}, {414.0, 72.0}}
                                Other, {{0.0, 232.0}, {414.0, 72.0}}
                                  Image, {{24.0, 259.0}, {18.0, 18.0}}
                                  Other, {{58.0, 254.0}, {49.5, 28.0}}
                                    Button, {{64.2, 257.5}, {37.1, 21.0}}, label: 'Buy with Touch Pay'
                                      StaticText, {{64.2, 257.5}, {0.0, 0.0}}
                                  StaticText, {{123.5, 258.5}, {75.5, 19.5}}, label: 'Touch Pay'
                                  Other, {{0.0, 303.5}, {414.0, 0.5}}
                              Cell, {{0.0, 304.0}, {414.0, 166.0}}
                                Other, {{0.0, 304.0}, {414.0, 166.0}}
                                  Button, {{16.0, 328.0}, {382.0, 60.0}}, label: 'Add New Item'
                                    StaticText, {{107.5, 348.0}, {199.0, 20.0}}, label: 'Add New Item'
                              Other, {{381.0, 105.5}, {30.0, 755.5}}, label: 'Vertical scroll bar, 1 page', value: 0%
                              Other, {{35.0, 863.0}, {344.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page', value: 0%
                Other, {{0.0, 840.0}, {414.0, 56.0}}
                  Other, {{0.0, 840.0}, {414.0, 0.5}}
                  Other, {{0.0, 840.0}, {414.0, 56.0}}
                    Button, {{0.0, 840.0}, {103.5, 56.0}}, identifier: 'tab_bar_title-main', label: 'Main'
                    Button, {{103.5, 840.0}, {103.5, 56.0}}, identifier: 'tab_bar_title-secondary', label: 'Secondary'
                    Button, {{207.0, 840.0}, {103.5, 56.0}}, identifier: 'tab_bar_title-todo', label: 'Todo'
                    Button, {{310.5, 840.0}, {103.5, 56.0}}, identifier: 'tab_bar_title-whatsup', label: 'Whatsup', Selected
  Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
    Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 896.0}, {414.0, 243.0}}
  Window (Main), {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
    Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, {{67.0, 350.0}, {280.0, 196.5}}
        StaticText, {{101.0, 384.0}, {212.0, 24.0}}, label: 'Remove Item'
        StaticText, {{101.0, 424.0}, {212.0, 38.0}}, label: 'Do you want to remove the Item?'
        Other, {{67.0, 486.0}, {280.0, 0.5}}
        Button, {{67.0, 486.5}, {140.0, 60.0}}, identifier: 'Cancel', label: 'Cancel'
          StaticText, {{112.0, 507.0}, {50.0, 19.0}}, label: 'Cancel'
        Other, {{207.0, 486.0}, {0.5, 60.5}}
        Button, {{207.5, 486.5}, {139.5, 60.0}}, identifier: 'Remove', label: 'Remove'
          StaticText, {{247.0, 506.5}, {61.0, 20.0}}, label: 'Remove'
    Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
      Other, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 896.0}}
```

So it's obviously finding both of those buttons. There are two buttons with the same staticText and Label. Is there a way I can easily have it tap whichever one is enabled or has current focus?

Also I'm curious if there's a way to convert what that UI Hierarchy dump is telling me into a workable query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can typically select the only, the first, the Nth, or the last button.

For the first use:

```swift
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.buttons["Remove"].tap()                                // the only
app.buttons["Remove"].element.tap()                        // the only
app.buttons["Remove"].firstMatch.tap()                     // the first
app.buttons["Remove"].element(boundBy: 3)                  // the fourth
app.buttons.matching(identifier: "Remove").lastMatch.tap() // the last
```

The last query requires extension:

```swift
extension XCUIElementQuery {
    var lastMatch: XCUIElement { return self.element(boundBy: self.count - 1) }
}
```

Read more about other queries here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery

You can also try tools like https://github.com/forqa/skeleton that generates lists of elements for you

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, figuring out which in the list of elements I wanted to tap and tapping that using a boundBy. Not great, but it works! And I can work with the developer to actually use unique identifiers, which is the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score -1):

In your code 
Instead of `XCUIApplication().buttons["Remove"].tap()`

put this `XCUIApplication().buttons["Remove"].firstMatch.tap()`

**OR**

You can use **query** to get first element

`XCUIApplication().buttons.matching(identifier: "Remove").element(boundBy: 0).tap()`

or second element

`XCUIApplication().buttons.matching(identifier: "Remove").element(boundBy: 1).tap()`